# Asynchronous cursor execution in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

(Submitting on behalf of a Snowflake user)

---

At the time of query execution on Snowflake, I need its query id. So I am using following code snippet:

```
cursor.execute(query, _no_results=True)

query_id = cursor.sfqid

cursor.query_result(query_id)
```

This code snippet working fine for small running queries. But for query which takes more than 40-45 seconds to execute, query_result function fails with `KeyError u'rowtype'`.

Stack trace:

```
File "snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 631, in query_result

self._init_result_and_meta(data, _use_ijson)

File "snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 591, in _init_result_and_meta

for column in data[u'rowtype']:

KeyError: u'rowtype'
```

Why would this error occur? How to solve this problem?

---

Any recommendations? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The Snowflake Python Connector allows for async SQL execution by using ​cur.execute(sql, _no_results=True)​

This ​"fire and forget"​ style of SQL execution allows for the parent process to continue without waiting for the SQL command to complete (think long-running SQL that may time-out).

If this is used, many developers will write code that captures the unique Snowflake Query ID (like you have in your code) and then use that Query ID to ​"check back on the query status later"​, in some sort of looping process.  When you check back to get the status, you can then get the results from that query_id using the result_scan( ) function.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html

I hope this helps...Rich